# Как отслеживать дату и время изменения модели?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Здравствуйте.

Использую [django-fsm](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-fsm), и есть необходимость при изменении статуса, фиксировать время этого изменения.

Вот статусы:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class State(object):
    NEW = 'new'              
    ACCEPTED = 'accepted'
    IN_PROGRESS = 'in_progress'


    STATES = (
        (NEW, _('New')),
        (ACCEPTED, _('Accepted')),
        (IN_PROGRESS, _('In progress')),
    )
```

А вот модель:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Example(ConcurrentTransitionMixin, Base):
    ...
    state = FSMField(
        default=State.NEW,
        choices=State.STATES,
        protected=True,
    )
    ...
```

И нужно, при изменении поля `state`, сохранить значение этого поля, и текущее время.

В [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), есть замечательная штука, как `MonitorField`, но минус в том, что это поле хранит в себе последние изменения, а мне нужен словарь изменений.

У кого какие идеи есть на этот счёт?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Подумал об вот таком варианте:

```
@cached_property
def state_changes(self):
    state_changes = dict()
    return state_changes

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Base, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.__state = self.state

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.state != self.__state:
        print('Поле состояния изменено')

    super(Base, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
    self.__state = self.name
```

Но так как у меня несколько моделей с полем `state`, нужно как-то `super` в `__init__` сделать таким образом, чтобы он мог поместиться в базовую модель, от которой наследуются те, что с полем `state`.

Comment: [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion)

Answer (score 0):

пусть поздно, но может кому пригодится.

можно добавить поле

```
 date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

она будет хранит дату и время последнего сохранения